# Is there any event to capture focus on a button control in mfc?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Basically now I am loading bitmap on a button as of four states as follows:

cases:

1. When I launch my application initially the buttons are being loaded with a bitmap.
2. When mouse hovering I am loading another bitmap.
3. And similarly loading bitmap on button click.
4. Finally fourth state is when I click tab the focus keeps on changing from one control to another, with rectangular dotted line .

In the `case4` I want to load one more bitmap when the button control gets the rectangular focus and should load another bitmap if once the button looses the focus.

I googled for long time and I did not get any clue to resolve this issue.

Initially, when I run my application it as follows:

[image]

Once when I click `Tab` the rectangular selection moves on to the button. Now, when the button control receives that rectangular focus I have to load a bitmap and when the button leaves focus I need to load another bitmap.

After `Tab` click

[image]

As for mouse hovering we have BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE event which get triggered and we can handle mouse entering and leaving. Similar to this do we have any which gets triggered when it receives are looses the focus?

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. But if the button has the `BS_NOTIFY` window style set, its parent window will get a `WM_COMMAND` message with the HIWORD set to `BN_SETFOCUS` when the button gains focus, and `BN_KILLFOCUS` when it loses it.

Comment: Thank you very much I forgot add BS_NOTIFY style to the button. Now, it is working.